# How can I give someone server access to only duplicate and modify a site?

Tags: security, server

I have ab Ubuntu server running multiple WordPress instances. I'd like to give someone access to the server and allow them to (1) copy an existing site, (2) modify it, and (3) deploy it.

However, I want to restrict their access so that they CANNOT (1) modify the existing site, (2) see any access passwords or secrets for the existing WordPress sites, (3) see any access passwords for anything else on the server, nor (4) intentionally or accidentally mess up any server settings.

Is there a way to achieve the above limited access and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: If they can copy a site, don't they copy all passwords and secrets in it?

Comment: I think this is more an server (ubuntu/directadmin/cpanel) related question. I think you have more luck here: https://askubuntu.com/ 

Beside that, if you are running Direct Admin (as administrator or reseller) with Installatron. It is possible to add a user to Direct Admin (with own login credentials), clone the Wordpress site to the newly created user with Installatron. From there the new user can only access the cloned site and not the original.

Comment: @kero passwords are stored in encrypted form in the db

Comment: @JorinvanVilsteren -- thanks, I think I'm just going to replicate the Ubuntu instance completely to another server (easy to do with Digital Ocean) and have the dev work on the server copy.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use a plugin like [Duplicator](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) to create an installer package of the complete site including database etc. which the user then can install in a new database & website path.